# Is there really no binary distribution of MySQLdb for Windows?

Tags: python, mysql

You have to build it yourself? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "official" binary, but I found some on [this site](http://www.codegood.com/?s=mysql-python) (for 2.6 32 or 64 bit, or 2.5 64 bit) via [the MySQLdb page on Pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/).  Also, [this blog](http://www.fuyun.org/2009/12/install-mysql-for-python-on-windows/) has instructions on how to build MySQLdb on Windows if you're feeling up to the task.

Comment: That's incredible. Is MySQLdb required for using MySql with Django? Can we trust a binary release from a 3rd party?

Comment: @Rhubarb: Yes, it's required.  "If you’re using MySQL, you’ll need MySQLdb, version 1.2.1p2 or higher. You will also want to read the database-specific notes for the MySQL backend." according to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#get-your-database-running ... If you don't want to take your chances, you'll have to build it yourself, from the looks of it.

Comment: Is Postgresql easier to use as the backend with Django? Seems it's as good if not more solid anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are, however, [oursql binaries for Windows](http://www.habnabit.org/software/oursql/). Read about oursql [here](http://packages.python.org/oursql/).